# How to reload PostgreSQL configuration

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I am trying to enable the transaction logs in PostgreSQL, where query run time is more than 3 seconds, by setting this flag

```
log_min_duration_statement = 3000
```

How to reload the configuration file without restarting the Postgres?

I've tried the below options and got these errors

```
1) postgres=# select pg_reload_config();
**ERROR:  function pg_reload_config() does not exist**
LINE 1: select pg_reload_config();
2) postgres@ospostgresql:/$ /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl reload
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.
```

Comment: It's `pg_reload_conf()` - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL

Comment: Thank you so much, I've followed that article only, but I've given the wrong syntax by following genric names like config()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thank you a_horse_with_no_name in helping to identify the typo which causes issue-1

```
1) postgres=# select pg_reload_config();
**ERROR:  function pg_reload_config() does not exist**
**-->** This is resolved by giving correct function name i.e. 
    select pg_reload_conf();

2) postgres@ospostgresql:/$ /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl reload
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.
**-->** This error is resolved by changing the user to postgres
    1) su postgres
    2) /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/11/main reload
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answer shows 2 ways to do this, but I found that there are 3 different ways to load Postgresql configuration. Apparently `systemctl reload postgresql` will also work.

Reference: https://www.heatware.net/postgresql/postgresql-reload-config-without-restarting/